# Compiling Qt3D under Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qmake, qt3d

I am trying to compile and install Qt3D via these directions:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt3D-Installation

I am using the Windows [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) method, and am using the Qt MinGW terminal.

The first time I did the process, it complained of a lack of [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl). This seems to go contrary to the tutorial. So I installed [Strawberry Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl). I couldn't find a recommendation for the flavor of Perl these build scripts expect on Windows.

When I say:

```
qmake qt3d.pro
```

It executes suspiciously fast.

When I say:

```
mingw32-make -j 3 install
```

I receive this error:

```
:\qt3d>mingw32-make -j 3 install
d src/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/bin/qmake.exe C:/qt3d/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && mingw32-make -f Makefile install
ingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'c:/qt3d/src'
d threed/ && ( test -e Makefile || c:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/bin/qmake.exe C:/qt3d/src/threed/threed.pro -o Makefile ) && c:/Qt/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make
f Makefile install
usr/bin/sh: c:/Qt/Tools/mingw48_32/bin/mingw32-make: Invalid argument
akefile:64: recipe for target 'sub-threed-install_subtargets-ordered' failed
ingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-threed-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 126
ingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt3d/src'
akefile:55: recipe for target 'sub-src-install_subtargets' failed
ingw32-make: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

Frankly, I'm not sure what to make of this error.

What might I be doing wrong?

The above errors were produced with Qt 5.1.

Here is a similar error I produced via exact same process for Qt 5.3.

```
C:\qt3d>mingw32-make -j 3 install
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/Qt/Qt5.3.0/5.3/mingw482_32/bin/qmake.exe C:/qt3d/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && mingw32-make -f Makefile install
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'c:/qt3d/src'
cd threed/ && ( test -e Makefile || c:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/bin/qmake.exe C:/qt3d/src/threed/threed.pro -o Makefile ) && c:/Qt/Qt5.3.0/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/ming
w32-make -f Makefile install
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'c:/qt3d/src/threed'
c:/Qt/Qt5.3.0/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release install
c:/Qt/Qt5.3.0/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug install
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'c:/qt3d/src/threed'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -fexceptions -mthreads -std=gnu++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_BUILD_3D_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_T
O_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D
_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_EGL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CO
RE_LIB -I. -I'../../include' -I'../../include/Qt3D' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0/Qt3D' -I'tmp' -I'../private' -I'global' -I'painting
' -I'arrays' -I'effects' -I'materials' -I'geometry' -I'viewing' -I'math3d' -I'scene' -I'scene_ai' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/code' -I'..
/../3rdparty/assimp/code/BoostWorkaround' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include/Compiler' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/ConvertU
TF' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/zlib' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/irrXML' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/unzip' -I'scene_bezier' -I'network' -I'grap
hicsview' -I'textures' -I'surfaces' -I'api' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtOpenGL' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtW
idgets' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.
1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/
include/QtNetwork' -I'.moc/release_shared' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o .obj/release_shared/qglpainter.o painting/qglpainter.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -fexceptions -mthreads -std=gnu++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_BUILD_3D_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_T
O_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D
_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_EGL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CO
RE_LIB -I. -I'../../include' -I'../../include/Qt3D' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0/Qt3D' -I'tmp' -I'../private' -I'global' -I'painting
' -I'arrays' -I'effects' -I'materials' -I'geometry' -I'viewing' -I'math3d' -I'scene' -I'scene_ai' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/code' -I'..
/../3rdparty/assimp/code/BoostWorkaround' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include/Compiler' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/ConvertU
TF' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/zlib' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/irrXML' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/unzip' -I'scene_bezier' -I'network' -I'grap
hicsview' -I'textures' -I'surfaces' -I'api' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtOpenGL' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtW
idgets' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.
1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/
include/QtNetwork' -I'.moc/release_shared' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o .obj/release_shared/qglattributedescription.o arrays/qglattributedesc
ription.cpp
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'c:/qt3d/src/threed'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -fexceptions -mthreads -std=gnu++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_BUILD_3D_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO
_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_
SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_DEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_EGL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
 -I. -I'../../include' -I'../../include/Qt3D' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0/Qt3D' -I'tmp' -I'../private' -I'global' -I'painting' -I'a
rrays' -I'effects' -I'materials' -I'geometry' -I'viewing' -I'math3d' -I'scene' -I'scene_ai' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/code' -I'../../3r
dparty/assimp/code/BoostWorkaround' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include/Compiler' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/ConvertUTF' -I
'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/zlib' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/irrXML' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/unzip' -I'scene_bezier' -I'network' -I'graphicsvi
ew' -I'textures' -I'surfaces' -I'api' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtOpenGL' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtWidgets
' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mi
ngw48_32/include/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/includ
e/QtNetwork' -I'.moc/debug_shared' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o .obj/debug_shared/qglpainter.o painting/qglpainter.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -fexceptions -mthreads -std=gnu++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_BUILD_3D_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO
_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_
SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_DEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_EGL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
 -I. -I'../../include' -I'../../include/Qt3D' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0/Qt3D' -I'tmp' -I'../private' -I'global' -I'painting' -I'a
rrays' -I'effects' -I'materials' -I'geometry' -I'viewing' -I'math3d' -I'scene' -I'scene_ai' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/code' -I'../../3r
dparty/assimp/code/BoostWorkaround' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include/Compiler' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/ConvertUTF' -I
'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/zlib' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/irrXML' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/unzip' -I'scene_bezier' -I'network' -I'graphicsvi
ew' -I'textures' -I'surfaces' -I'api' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtOpenGL' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtWidgets
' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mi
ngw48_32/include/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/includ
e/QtNetwork' -I'.moc/debug_shared' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o .obj/debug_shared/qglvertexbundle.o arrays/qglvertexbundle.cpp
painting/qglpainter.cpp: In member function 'int QGLPainter::pickObject(int, int) const':
painting/qglpainter.cpp:2348:29: error: 'class QOpenGLFunctions' has no member named 'glReadPixels'
     context()->functions()->glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                             ^
painting/qglpainter.cpp: In member function 'int QGLPainter::pickObject(int, int) const':
painting/qglpainter.cpp:2348:29: error: 'class QOpenGLFunctions' has no member named 'glReadPixels'
     context()->functions()->glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                             ^
Makefile.Release:4156: recipe for target '.obj/release_shared/qglpainter.o' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [.obj/release_shared/qglpainter.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt3d/src/threed'
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'release-install' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [release-install] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -fexceptions -mthreads -std=gnu++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_BUILD_3D_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO
_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_
SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_DEBUG -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_EGL -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
 -I. -I'../../include' -I'../../include/Qt3D' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0' -I'../../include/Qt3D/5.3.0/Qt3D' -I'tmp' -I'../private' -I'global' -I'painting' -I'a
rrays' -I'effects' -I'materials' -I'geometry' -I'viewing' -I'math3d' -I'scene' -I'scene_ai' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/code' -I'../../3r
dparty/assimp/code/BoostWorkaround' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/include/Compiler' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/ConvertUTF' -I
'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/zlib' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/irrXML' -I'../../3rdparty/assimp/contrib/unzip' -I'scene_bezier' -I'network' -I'graphicsvi
ew' -I'textures' -I'surfaces' -I'api' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtOpenGL' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtWidgets
' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtGui/5.1.1/QtGui' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mi
ngw48_32/include/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/include/QtCore/5.1.1/QtCore' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/includ
e/QtNetwork' -I'.moc/debug_shared' -I'C:/Qt/5.1.1/mingw48_32/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o .obj/debug_shared/qarray.o arrays/qarray.cpp
Makefile.Debug:4155: recipe for target '.obj/debug_shared/qglpainter.o' failed
mingw32-make[3]: *** [.obj/debug_shared/qglpainter.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt3d/src/threed'
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'debug-install' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [debug-install] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt3d/src/threed'
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'sub-threed-install_subtargets-ordered' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-threed-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'c:/qt3d/src'
Makefile:55: recipe for target 'sub-src-install_subtargets' failed
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2

C:\qt3d>
```

A similar error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `It executes suspiciously fast.` -> I think you wish to run qmake recursively in a recursive build system structure. That means you would need to pass the `-r` option to qmake, which is passed by default if you use QtCreator, I think. You need to be explicit on the command line.

Comment: As it turns out I had to use the -r flag, change some of the source code, and use an older version of the qt terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into a proper answer:

> Q: It executes suspiciously fast.

You wish to run qmake recursively in a recursive build system structure such as `Qt3D`. That means you would need to pass the -r option to qmake, which is passed by default if you use QtCreator. You need to be explicit on the command line when running qmake manually.

Also, note that the "old" (current master) Qt3D code base is unmaintained, so there might be issues with upcoming Qt versions, albeit it got some patches back then to work with Qt 5 better. If you get issues due to new Qt version, you could create and hopefully send patches or just downgrade your main Qt version.

Comment: To get it to build I also had to use an older version of QT terminal (5.1). It seems to work OK with QT 5.3, but I having some issues.

Comment: @baordog: Qt, not QT. ;-) Not sure what you mean by "terminal" in that context. You just mean the main Qt version, right?

Comment: The tutorial I referenced above stipulates that use a special terminal provided by QT (which comes with each qt distribution) it's like Qt MinGw.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you have with Qt 5.3, building Qt3D with Qt 5.2.1 on Windows 7. I resolved it by changing `context->functions()->glReadPixels()` by just `glReadPixels ()` at line 2348 in qglpainter.cpp.

It is because of this error in the terminal:

```
painting/qglpainter.cpp: In member function 'int QGLPainter::pickObject(int, int) const':
painting/qglpainter.cpp:2348:29: error: 'class QOpenGLFunctions' has no member named 'glReadPixels'
     context()->functions()->glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Now Qt3D is installed.

Comment: Yes, this helped. I got everything up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody who still have problems while compiling, after installing perl on your machine, have a look at the path to the qt3d folder. There should be no spaces in it.